# Triggering a server request (ajax?) after page render to re-render certain parts of the page in apache wickets

Tags: ajax, wicket, wicket-1.5

On my page there is a panel that shows a list of car dealers. The panel displays a list of dealers with information for each dealer as mentioned below.

- For each dealer I need to show : name, address, phone, hours. The data is in json.
- *name, address, phone* : they are simple text-labels.
- *hours*: There is a link "View hours" for each deaaler. On clicking it, a text-label slides down the link showing "loading-gif" if hours data not yet present, else shows the hours data. Clicking link again hides the hours data.

When the page is rendered, this is the behavior I need:

- On page render I show *name, address, phone* labels & the *hours* link. As of now I do **NOT** have the hours information in json.
- After the page renders, I want to make a request to the server (Ajax ?), get the updated json with hours information & re-render the "view hours" so that when clicked it now shows the hours. *This is what I do not know how to do.*

Why am I not sending a json with hours information initially itself? This is because collecting that is expensive & very rarely will the "View Hours" link be used. So collecting all that data upfront will make the page render slow. I want the event/act of page loading trigger a request to get hours data & re-render **only** the hours text-label that slides down on clicking the "View Hours" link.

I looked at `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` but its trigger is a time duration, not the page load.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `view hours` links will be used "Very Rarely" ,according to you, it would be best to fetch those data on demand, rather than pulling them all up during/after page load.

This would in turn reduce the overhead of collecting a lot of data in the page and also free you from associating each data with each records, parsing them and putting them in HTML.

Comment: Thanks. That did occur to me but "view hours" is still a functionality, and we decided that instead of making user wait after clicking it, why not utilize the time while the user is browsing the page to load the extra stuff. So I would not be making ajax request per click on the "view hours" button. I would like to get ALL hours information and render ALL the "view hours" text-labels after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "view hours" link and the code to get the data on a Panel, then lazyload that panel using an AjaxLazyLoadPanel http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/how-do-use-ajaxlazyloadpanel-in-wicket/. You could show a loading-gif, for each link, while the application gathers the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `AjaxLazyLoadPanel` for this (as drobson suggested). This works very nice but in your scenario it might have 1 drawback. Each hour to be updated will be a synchronous AJAX call so each one needs to be updated separately. This might mean more traffic and a not ideal user experience.

Another alternative might be to add a `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior` to your page which will update the hours (and add the whole panel to the target). You can call the method generated by this behavior when the document has loaded.

```
    this.add(new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {

        @Override
        protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            //calculate hours + add list or whatever to the target
        }

        @Override
        protected CharSequence getCallbackScript() {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            result.append("function resetHours() {\n");
            result.append("wicketAjaxPost('" + this.getCallbackUrl() + "', null, function(){}, function(){});" + "\n");
            result.append("}\n");
            return result;
        }
    });
```

And the call:

```
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    response.renderOnLoadJavaScript("resetHours()");
}
```